# Difference of Total in the same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this Column,

```
  ID  Year  ColumnDesc  Amount   
  1    2000   Taken       100
  1    2000  NotTaken    10
  1    2001   Taken       200
  1    2001  NotTaken   100
```

So i need to do the Difference between the Amounts with same ID and Year so my table should look like.

```
  ID  Year  ColumnDesc  Amount   
  1    2000   Taken    90
  1    2001   Taken    100
```

Can any one help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select id, year, 'Taken' as ColumnDesc,
       sum(case when ColumnDesc = 'Taken' then Amount
                when ColumnDesc = 'Not Taken' then - Amount
                else 0
           end) as Amount
from t
group by id, year;
```

Comment: @snp.it . . . What do you mean?  That is the value in your sample results.